# Basic resistor question

Tags: resistors

Some softball for you guys: I've got a circuit on a scooter that consists of a 12V battery, a 10 amp fuse, a switch and an LED. The battery goes to a number of other things as does the ground, but when I power the circuit in question, the fuse blows. A 50W 25ohm resistor solves this issue but the resistor is getting too hot for comfort. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a schematic showing how you have connected everything, and a link to the manufacturer's datasheet (not to amazon or ebay or aliexpress) for the LED.

Comment: Motors take 10 rated current starting up. Most fuses will blow in a few seconds at 10x rated current. If you want to scoot hardball, get a bigger fuse and battery or a slow blow fuse

Comment: If that's a power LED module, it usually wants a constant current of 300mA running through it. You can limit the current with a resistor but the usual way to do it for power LEDs is using a small DC/DC converter with constant current output. Those are meant for power LED modules and marketed at the same place as power LED modules.

Comment: There are way too many things to this to just give a simple answer. The problem you are having is very unlikely to be the only problem you have. Basically, there is a certain amount of system design involved in wiring up an E-bike or scooter. It is not super complicated but you seem to be starting from near zero. Isn't there someone with more experience you can get to help you?

Comment: If this is existing equipment that used to work there is a 'fault'. Isolate the wiring to each oif "a number of things" and test them one at a tome OR connect a hall cell cirrent probe over each wire in turn and determine which draws the high current. As Tony notes, a slow-blow fuse may help. A lot more detail will help this question survive.

Answer (score 0):

> when I power the circuit in question, the fuse blows.

An LED by itself will not limit current. If you have a voltage source \$V\$, resistor \$R\$ and LED in series, the current through the circuit will be \$I = (V-2)/R\$.

(The 2 represents the voltage drop of the LED which can be different for different LEDs. 2 volts is a typical value for small red LEDs.)

As you can see, if \$R\$ is 0 or close to it, \$I\$ will be very large. This explains why your fuse blew.

> A 50W 25ohm resistor solves this issue but the resistor is getting too hot for comfort. What can I do?

The power \$P\$ dissipated by the the resistor is \$I^2R\$ where \$I\$ is as given above. In terms of \$V\$ this is \$P = (V-2)^2/R\$. To reduce the power \$P\$ you can reduce \$V\$ or increase \$R\$.

Generally for small LEDs you don't want to run more than 10 mA through an LED.

Comment: Are you saying a 10 mA LED can carry enough current for long enough to blow a 10A fuse?

Comment: Okay, I have to apologize. I confused myself. There is no LED on this circuit. Just the battery, the fuse, the switch and the ground. So if I follow your math above (omitting the -2) I get: I = 12V/25ohms = 0.48A and therefore P = (0.48^2)*25 = 5.76W.  What I don't understand is why, if that's correct, a 50W resistor would get so hot when only handling 5.76W.

Comment: Your "50W" resistor may just be marketing. Here are two 100W power resistors... the grid spacing is 1/2-inch. One is manufactured by Dale which was founded in 1947; the other came from ebay: https://imgur.com/a/9tLzUVX

Comment: The one the bottom is identical to the one I have. Same writing and everything. To be safe, I think I'll just buy a couple more from different manufacturers and place them in line if I have to. I appreciate the guidance!